# Text continues beyond margin when using \mu

Tags: symbols, line-breaking

Whenever I use the command `\mu` in my text, the entire paragraph after µ will be printed in Italic and continues beyond the textwidth. All spaces are removed. Does anybody know what is happening and how to prevent this?

Comment: You didn't give an example but my guess is that you should check your log-file for error messages. `\mu` is a math command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\mu` is a math mode command so TeX will issue an error and insert a `$` before it, the rest of the paragraph will then be in math. Use `$\mu$`

Comment: aargh, I was already writing the same answer... +1 for you!

Comment: Ah, is it that simple? Thank you very much, I can't believe I did not figure that out myself.